# C# delete XML node based off the inner text without knowing the parent nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have a document structured such as the below, and I am trying to delete all such occurrences of "DELETE ME". There is no XPath pattern behind this. What is the best way to do this?

Original XML is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
  <PageInfo>
   <ID>0</ID>
   <NUM>DELETE ME</NUM>
   <URL>er.php</URL>
  </PageInfo>
  <SomeOtherAttributeName>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <NUM> 
       <INDX>DELETE ME</INDX>
       <somethingElse>keep me here</somethingElse>
   </NUM>
   <URL>/out/out.ViewFolder.php</URL>
  </SomeOtherAttributeName>
</Data>
```

Desired output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
  <PageInfo>
   <ID>0</ID>
   <URL>er.php</URL>
  </PageInfo>
  <SomeOtherAttributeName>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <NUM> 
       <somethingElse>keep me here</somethingElse>
   </NUM>
   <URL>/out/out.ViewFolder.php</URL>
  </SomeOtherAttributeName>
</Data>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "There is no XPath pattern behind this" ?

Comment: I mean that I do not want to search "Data/PageInfo/Num" to get to "DELETE ME". I want to find all such nodes that have the inner text of "DELETE ME" and then delete those nodes from the original XML.

Comment: how huge is the file/string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Xml Linq.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication75
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> deleteMe = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (string)x == "DELETE ME").ToList();

            for (int i = deleteMe.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                deleteMe[i].Remove();
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: you miss doc.Save("c:\temp\test.new.xml") :)